# Join Tables with Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, group-by

I have an SQL query with a `COALESCE` operator to concatenate all rows in one row with a delimiter (`;`). Here's the code to build the query:

```
DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(max)  
SELECT @db = COALESCE(@db+';','') + OID FROM COD_TBL
SELECT OID = @db
INNER JOIN EMP_TBL ON EMP_TBL.ID=COD_TBL.ID
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this returned.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

TABLE 1: EMP_TBL

```
ID NAME  
1  RICHARD
2  RAYMOND
```

TABLE 2: COD_TBL

```
ID COD
1  AA
2  BB
1  CC
2  DD
1  EE
2  FF
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
ID NAME     OID  
1  RICHARD  AA;CC;EE
2  RAYMOND  BB;DD;FF
```

Please help me fix the query.

Comment: A `join` is typically part of a `from` clause. Your second `select` doesn't have a `from` clause, hence the problem with joining. Aside: [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't concatenate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option use string aggregation function `string_agg()` - available starting SQL Server 2017:

```
select e.id, e.name, string_agg(cod, ';') within group(order by cod) oid
from emp_tbl e
inner join code_tbl c on c.id = e.id
group by e.id, e.name
```